# how to set minimum acceptable recognition accuracy?

Tags: noise, threshold, sphinx4

I need to recognize key words in long speech audio file (wav). 
There can be different noise, clicks, clangs, etc. 
This sounds are often recognized as keywords.

How can I set some threshold to distinguish words correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not set that. Keyword spotting functionality is not supported by sphinx4.

Comment: Is it possible to get some probability from Result class? Like, this is word "one" with probability 10%?